# How should we have an interger like counter value in javascript map?

Tags: javascript, maps

How can I create a value in java script map to behave like integer counter.

var map = { "cars" : count, "buses" : count };

```
The way I want to use this map is:
if (car) {
   // incremeent the count of cars
} else {
   // increment the count of busses
}
```

My question is how should such a map look like syntactically in javascript ?

Comment: How do you know if an item is a car or a bus?  `if (car)` just checks to see if there's any truthy value in `car`.  Don't you need to check if the type is a `"car"` somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize it like this:

```
var map = {cars: 0, buses: 0 };
```

Then, you can increment like this:

```
if (car) {
    ++map.cars;
} else {
    ++map.buses;
}
```

But, I suspect you need a little more logic to your `if (car)` so you can actually tell that it is a car type, not just a boolean but you haven't shown us how that part of your code works to know exactly what to suggest.

---

You could also be a little more object oriented and put the method on the map:

```
var map = {
    cars: 0, 
    buses: 0,
    count: function(obj) {
        if (obj) {
            ++this.cars;
        } else {
            ++this.buses;
        }
    }
};

map.count(item);
```

Again, you'll have to modify the `if (obj)` portion of this to actually discern whether the type is a car or not, but you haven't disclosed enough about your code to know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var counts = { cars: 0, buses: 0 };

if (car) {
    counts.cars++;
} else {
    counts.buses++;
}

// or more succinctly:
counts[car ? 'cars' : 'buses']++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parameter, say *vehicles*,  whose value is either *cars* or *buses*, then you can do:

```
map[vehicles]++;
```

You can also do:

```
map[car? 'cars' : 'buses']++;
```

If you show more of what you are doing, more help can be provided on what is likely to be most appropriate.